# What does Base b2 = new Child(); signify?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
 class Base {

    public void add() {
        System.out.println("Base ADD");
    }

    void subtract() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

}

class Child extends Base {

    public void add(){
        System.out.println("Child ADD");
    }

    public void subtract() {
        System.out.println("Child Subtract");
    }

}

class MainClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Base b1 = new Base();
        Base b2 = new Child();

        Child b3 = new Child();

        b1.add();

        b2.subtract();  

        b2.add();
        b3.subtract();

    }

}
```

I am somewhat confused with the above code. The line most confusing me is

```
Base b2 = new Child();
```

and

```
 b2.subtract();
```

What I understand is at compile time compiler checks weather `Base` class has `subtract()` method or not, then at runtime runtime polymorphism occurs as object is of type `Child`.

The question is how or where we can use this line i.e. `Base b2 = new Child();`

In what scenario we should use this? Please help, it would be great!

Comment: Basically you can use it when need an object of type `Base` with behavior of `Child`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the two parts of the statement:

```
Base b2
```

that declares a variable called `b2` of type `Base`. You can assign a reference to that variable if the reference is null or refers to an instance of `Base` or a subclass of `Base`.

Then

```
new Child()
```

creates a new instance of `Child`. `Child` is a subclass of `Base`, so you can assign the reference returned by the constructor to the `b2` variable.

Now, you can only "see" members of `Base` through `b2`, even though the actual value refers to an instance of `Child` at execution time. But any methods from `Base` which have been *overridden* in `Child` will use the overridden version when they're called... so when you call

```
b2.subtract();
```

the JVM finds out the *actual* type of the object that `b2` refers to, and uses that class's implementation of `subtract` - in this case, the method which prints "Child Subtract".

EDIT: You've specifically asked where you can use this sort of thing, and how it helps...

You can use it any time you want to declare a variable of a more general type (a superclass or an interface) but assign a value to it which happens to be a subclass or an implementation of the interface. As another example:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The main advantage of declaring a variable in a general way is that you're retaining flexibility - later on you could change from using `ArrayList<T>` to some other implementation of `List<T>`, and the code should still work. You're basically saying, "I only need the members and guarantees provided by `List<T>` - the fact that I'm using `ArrayList<T>` is somewhat incidental."

A similar example is deciding what type a method should return - often you want to only declare that you return a general type (or interface) even though the implementation knows which concrete type it's returning. That hides the implementation details, which allows you to change them later.

Comment: I think the OP question is about where to use `Base b = new Child();` instead of `Child b = new Child();`, isn't it?

Comment: @khachik: I've been editing the answer to give a bit more detail. It's not quite clear to what extent the OP understands how it works and is just after "best practice" advice.

Comment: @on Skeet: I completely agree with the execution part. But I wanted to know the logical significance of this. Like how this would help in coding logically?

Comment: "variable of type `b2`" - isn't the type `Base` and the name `b2`?

Comment: An advantage you didn't mention is that it doesn't just allow flexibility for future *changes* to the code--the variable will also allow a reference to other implementations of `List<String>` to be stored into it.  It's not uncommon for a method to initialize a variable with a default of one particular type, but have methods which may set it to other types.

Answer (score 2):

```
Base b2 = new Child();
```

You can use Reference of Super for object  of child.

for
    b2.method();

at compile time you must have  method(); in BaseClass.

At run time the Object's method will get invoked so here object is Child from `Base b2 = new Child();`

So child's `method()` version will get executed.

**Usage:**

> Polymorphism is extremely useful in designing enterprise-level systems, as you can create and define multiple interface layers that allow outside parties or outside software to interact with your system in a particular way. We all know how helpful it is in system integration to have a published API, but if interior system changes become necessary, the API may have to be republished and integrated systems may have to be reworked. To avoid this, careful consideration should be given to object APIs as well as the overall system APIs during design. One way to ensure that a robust system can deal with objects that have more complex methodologies than were originally intended is to have the object API be polymorphic. This way, the system knows a "face" of the object being passed to it, but doesn't have to be aware of extemporaneous changes.

**Also see**

- [Standard Docs on **Polymorphism**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)
- [Resource](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0508/barnabee/index.html)

Comment: life.java Yeah I agree with the above explanation. But I wanted to like whats the use of this Line. In what scenario it can be use. How it would help ?

Comment: @Sam , it will make abstract structure of your OO design, further you will get chance at runtime which version of method to exetcute