# When can a reference's type differ from the type of its object?

Tags: oop, inheritance

Yesterday I was asked a question in an interview:

Suppose `class A` is a base class, and `class B` is derived class.

Is it possible to create object of:

```
class B = new class A?
class A = new class B?
```

If yes, then what happen?

Answer (score 1):

Objects of type B are guaranteed to also be objects of type A. This type of relationship is called ["Is-a,"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) or inheritance, and in OOP it's a standard way of getting [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). For example, if objects of type A have a method `foo()`, objects of type B must also provide it, but its behavior is allowed to differ.

The reverse is not *necessarily* true: an object of type A (the base class) won't always be an object of type B (the derived class). Even if it is, this can't be guaranteed at compile-time, so what happens for your first line is that **the code will fail to compile**.

What the second line does depends on the language, but generally

- Using a reference with the base type will restrict you to only accessing only members which the base type is guaranteed to have.
- In Java, if member names are "hidden" (A.x exists and so does B.x, but they have different values), when you try to access the member you will get the value which corresponds to the type of the *reference* rather than the type of the *object*.

The code in your second example is standard practice when you are more interested in an API than its implementation, and want to make your code as generic as possible. For instance, often in Java one writes things like `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>()`. If you decide to use a linked list implementation later, you will not have to change any code which uses `list`.

Take a look at this related question: [What does Base b2 = new Child(); signify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447924/what-does-base-b2-new-child-signify)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, automatic conversions are allowed *down* the hierarchy, but not *up*. That is, you can automatically convert a derived class to its base class, but not the reverse. So only your second example is possible. `class A = new class B` should be ok since the derived class *B* can be converted to the base class *A*. But `class B = new class A` will not work *automatically*, but may be implemented by supplying an explicit conversion (overloading the constructor).

Comment: k fine but tell me 1 thing if there is methods(getData()) with same name in Base class A as well as derived class B and if i create object like Class A=new Class B(); then which one called 1st ...in base class method or derived class method???

Comment: @johncip's answer addresses this nicely, I think. This question depends on the language.

Answer (score 0):

A is super class and B is a SubClass/Derived Class 
the Statement
class A = new class B     is always possible and it is called Upcasting  because you are going Up in terms of  more specific to more General 
Example:

Fruit class is a Base Class and Apple Class is Derived
we can that Apple is more specific and must possess all the quality of an Fruit
so you can always  do UPcasting where as

DownCasting is not always possible because  Apple a=new Fruit();
A fruit can be a Apple or may it is not